# Text in drop down sets other text fields as disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

I have an ASPX form with a multiple fields.

The field in question (the drop down) when selected should disable another drop down and text field but for some reason it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<td class="td"><asp:DropDownList ID="DeliveryTypeList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="javascript:changeTextFields();"></asp:DropDownList></td>
```

The javascript I have is:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function changeTextFields() {
    var val = document.getElementById("DeliveryTypeList").text;
    if (val == "PO Box 110") {document.getElementById("ReceivedFrom").disabled = false;  document.getElementById("ReferenceNumber").disabled = false }
    if (val == "Courier Delivery") { document.getElementById("ReceivedFrom").disabled = true; document.getElementById("ReferenceNumber").disabled = false }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide full code to understand..

Answer (score 1):

Your client code may be fine but your problem is `AutoPostback = true` on `DeliveryTypeList`. This setting causes client to post to server on selected index change, so code in `changeTextFields` is irrelevant.

If you require `AutoPostback = true` then you'll have to add some extra logic on server side to execute your client code on postback.

Answer (score 0):

The id for the drop down will never be the same, since its a server side control. Use class instead in the Java Script.

Check

> [Hiding a div when dropdown selected value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323251/hiding-a-div-when-dropdown-selected-value-changes/5323327#5323327)

for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain the client state, you want to call the script on page load after returning back from server.

Since you are using javascript, you can use `e.options[e.selectedIndex].value` to retrieve the dropdownlist's selected value.

My Thought: Using jQuery would be a lot easier to select DOM compare to javascript.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DeliveryTypeList" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" onchange="javascript:changeTextFields();">
    <asp:ListItem Text="PO Box 110" Value="PO Box 110" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Courier Delivery" Value="Courier Delivery" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ReceivedFrom" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="ReferenceNumber" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeTextFields() {
        var e = document.getElementById('<%= DeliveryTypeList.ClientID %>');
        var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if (val == "PO Box 110") {
            alert(val);
            document.getElementById('<%= ReceivedFrom.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('<%= ReferenceNumber.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        }
        if (val == "Courier Delivery") {
            alert(val);
            document.getElementById('<%= ReceivedFrom.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= ReferenceNumber.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        }
    }
    // Call at page load
    changeTextFields();
</script>
```